# Shimano Sora 3500 (3x9) and Alivio front derailleur

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, shifter, chainring

Please help rebuild my bike :)
I have Scott Sub 30 2011 http://www.evanscycles.com/products/scott/sub-30-2011-hybrid-bike-ec025449 and right now I would like to change shifters to **Shimano Sora 3500 (3x9)**.

I'm wondering - these shifters will work with front derailleur and crank?

Crank: Alivio FC-M430-8

Chainrings: 48 × 36 × 26 T

And front derailleur: Shimano Alivio FD-M430

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It should work fine with your chain and chainset, but are you planning on changing your bars too?  You may need to change your FD, but they are cheap.

Comment: @RoKa Thank you for your answer. Of course, I will change handlebar too (road handlebar). And brakes (to mini v-brakes).
You're right, FD is cheap. If I will have to buy another, I will choose Sora series.

Comment: Careful changing the bars from flat to drops.  It might mess up the geometry and maneuverability of you bike more than you would expect.

Comment: @Kibbbee - I know what you mean.
I was trying road bar to my bike. It seems that everything will be ok :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that based on the fact that you have a standard KMC-9 chain, and that you're keeping it 9-sp all round, you should be all-right.

As noted in the comments, you'll need to change your bars too else you'll not be able to shift and brake correctly, but you said you are.

Only thing I am not too sure of, is the FD. If I were you, I'd just try to use the Alivio you have, and if you have any issues, just replace it with a Sora FD-3503.  They are cheap enough.

Comment: Thank you again ;) 

In a few days I'll go to a friendly bicycle repair. If I will have to buy only shifters, brakes and front derailleur (and of course the handlebar) - I will order parts.
If I will have to replace the crank, chainrings and chain - I'll think about all this "great plan" :).
In Poland, bicycle parts are not cheap.

Comment: I'm happy to help. I don't think you'll need to worry about the crank, chainrings or chain :-)

Comment: You are awesome! :) I'll let you know when I'll start to collect new parts :) Thanks again!